# Ignore changes in file under TFS

Tags: .net, tfs

I got some file `Foo` under TFS source control.
`Foo` is always modified by my script when i build my project (its related to project installer).
So for now i always need to `check-out` `Foo` to build my project, then discard any changes made in file before `check-in` to keep original default version.

Is there any way to have `Foo` under source control, but **always** ignore any changes made in this file and never check-out it even when i change it (check-out only if i forcely choose it).

Comment: Generated files in source control is an antipattern. Is there a specific reason you want it to be tracked by TFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a .[tfignore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx) file available?